# IE 8 fixed width select issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I have to specify a width to the `select` in my html.

It works fine in all browsers except in IE8, which cuts the text that is more than the width

CSS

```
select {
        border: 1px solid #65A6BA;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-left: 22px;
        width: 166px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<select>
        <option value="1">Some text</option>
        <option value="2">Text Larger Than the Width of select</option>
        <option value="3">Some text</option>
        <option value="4">Some text</option>
        <option value="5">Some text</option>
    </select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj7Pp/)

I am open to js, jquery solutions, but would prefer a css only solution

Comment: you want to fix the width and after that you want if text is more then your select menu should increase rite ?

Comment: I imagine you will never get ideal results. IE8 (and below) has been programmed to display select lists like that. Bit of Googling and this springs up: http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/ which kind of works, it makes the select box wider when hovering in IE. Problems might arise, however, depending on how you position your `select` element. If it's just inline, then suddenly changing the width could shift other things around.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution would not work for me, because the select is in a menu and that would cause the menu to distort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page in question was a very old page and it forces IE 8 to go into compatibility mode, so the css solution did not work.

I ended fixing it using the following piece of `jquery`

Assume the select has a class of `fixedWidth`

```
$el = $("select.fixedWidth");
$el.data("origWidth", $el.outerWidth()) 

$el.mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("width", "auto");
  })
  .bind("blur change", function(){
    el = $(this);
    el.css("width", el.data("origWidth"));
  });
```

Comment: i cannot get result from this can you give a demo on jsfiddle please. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Fixed it!

Here is the revised jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PLqzQ/

The trick is adding the `focus` selector to your CSS so that it looks like this:

```
select {
        border: 1px solid #65A6BA;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-left: 22px;
        width: 166px;
        overflow:visible ;
    }

select:focus { width:auto ;
position:relative ;
}​
```

I tested it in IE8 and it works like a charm.

VERY IMPORTANT: You have to add a Doctype Definition to your Code otherwise the fix won't work for IE8.

Example 
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Comment: The behavior is clumsy and not as it behaves in other browsers. The length of the select text shouldn't be widened but the drop down.

Comment: @NitinRam this is not a very nice solution indeed but at least it works. We are trying to fix a browser issue so lucky we get one already :) I would apply this CSS to ie8 only though

Answer (score 2):

I found all the other answers to be really flaky and over-complicated. This can be easily accomplished with the following CSS (at least in my case):

```
html.IE8 .SelectContainer {
    position: relative;
}

html.IE8 .SelectContainer select {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto; /* Or fixed if you want. */
    max-width: 100%;
}

html.IE8 .SelectContainer select:focus {
    max-width: none;
}
```

I set a class on the `html` element if the browser is IE8 (or less) (Google how to do this).

Put your `select` inside a `.SelectContainer` and when you click it, it will expand as needed.

No need for jQuery, conditional comments, etc. Much simpler and works much smoother, for my needs, at least.

I hope none of you ever have to employee this.

It's time for the US gov't to upgrade to a modern browser!

Comment: Much better than using JS. Possibly wrap the styles inside         

    <!--[if IE 8]>
            
        <![endif]-->

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and also tried *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* but I thought it was very clumsy-looking.  I checked the [event list for select elements (from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and tried using *beforeactivate* and *deactivate* intead.  It worked much more smoothly in my opinion.  Tested on a page running in IE8 directly (not compatibility mode):

```
$('select').beforeactivate(function () {
    var isIE8 = $.browser.version.substring(0, 2) === "8.";
    if (!isIE8)
        return;
    $(this).css('width', 'auto');

});

$('select').deactivate(function () {
    var isIE8 = $.browser.version.substring(0, 2) === "8.";
    if (!isIE8)
        return;
    $(this).css('width', '166px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a handy plugin i stumbled upon while sorting IE8 issues. Do have a look, [IE8 EXPAND SELECT WIDTH](http://powerkiki.github.io/ie_expand_select_width/). Works amazing. Easy plug-n-play.

Answer (score 0):

[follow the link it may help.](http://jsfiddle.net/FSsG8/1/)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
      $("#width_tmp").html($('select option:selected').text());
      $(this).width($("#width_tmp").width()+30); // 30 : the size of the down arrow of the select box 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you should change the `width` attribute setting: instead of fixed `168px` use `width:auto;` Should work perfectly.

Comment: The width is necessary. Cant specify auto